# Can I combine PySP and pyomo.DAE to do stochastic dynamic programming?

Tags: pyomo

It is unclear to me whether PySP and pyomo.DAE can be combined. I wish to use stochastic dynamic programming to model optimal stopping/real options valuation. I wish to use stochastic differential equations, geometric Brownian motion, and the Bellman equation. I get that PySP does stochastic programming, and I get that pyomo.DAE does dynamic optimization. Does Pyomo have the built in capacity to do stochastic dynamic programming?

Answer (score 0):

PySP and Pyomo.DAE can be combined but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for. See [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135417304040) on a few applications that combine them. The dynamic optimization support in Pyomo.DAE is not the same as dynamic programming (See the documentation [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling_extensions/dae.html)). If you could provide a small example of the exact problem structure you're trying to represent then I would be able to say more definitively if we support it or not.

Comment: I suppose a better formulation of the question might have been: is there a preexisting stochastic dynamic programing (OR use of the word) package in python. The answer to that seems to be: yes, stochasticdp. More specifically, the my problem that I am trying to code stated mathematically is:

Comment: I suppose a better formulation of the question might have been: is there a preexisting stochastic dynamic programing (OR use of the word) package in python. The answer to that seems to be: yes, stochasticdp. More specifically, the my problem that I am trying to code stated mathematically is: F (V) = max E(V_t* - C) * exp(-rt*)] where V = pI and dI = I(1-I/N)(b*dt + s*dW). Where dW is a Wiener process.